# ImplicitRegion does not work in simple case

Tags: plotting, graphics, backslide

Why doesn't this work: `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[1 == 0.2 x + 0.5 y, {x, y}]]`, while this, which is almost the same works: `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[1 == 0.2 x + y, {x, y}]]`?

I cannot discover a general rule, but sometimes `ImplicitRegion` does not work in the simplest linear cases. E.g. this also doesn't work: `RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[10 - 2 x - 5 y == 0, {x, y}]]`, but replace the 10 with 1 and it works again.

Comment: works as expected in v 13.1. A work-around for v 12.3 is to wrap `ImplicitRegion` with `DiscretizeRegion`, i.e.,  use `RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[1 ==.2 x+.5 y, {x, y}]]`.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! And for letting me know that there is Mathematica 13 :)

Comment: ivan, sorry it was a typo; I meant v 11.3 :)

Comment: I tagged this [tag:backslide] based on @kglr's comment. I can't check that personally, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add bounds, `RegionPlot` will work, even if bounds on only one variable:

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[1 == 0.2 x + 0.5 y, {{x, -1, 1}, y}]]
```

The bounds `RegionPlot` tries by default are

```
{{-1.`, 1.`}, {-1.`, 1.`}}
```

The line `1 == 0.2 x + 0.5 y` does not intersect this square, so you get an empty region; here is the call the `RegionPlot` makes in this case:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[
  1 == 0.2 x + 0.5 y, {x, y}], {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}},
 {MaxCellMeasure -> Automatic, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞, 
  Method -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Automatic}]
```

In the OP's second example, the line `1 == 0.2 x + y` does intersect the square, so we get a nonempty region, which is plotted.

Since the `RegionBounds` on such lines are `{{-∞, ∞}, {-∞, ∞}}`, `RegionPlot` chooses bounds arbitrarily.  I suppose WRI could enhance it by considering special cases -- lines are fairly easy to detect but perhaps rare, perhaps not in actual use -- is it worth it?  That's a decision for WRI, and one factor is probably the level of user complaints.  WRI does like things to work `Automatic`, overall a strength of Mathematica imho, but perfect `Automatic` behavior cannot be achieved (also an opinion, I suppose).

It's curious that `DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[..]` works better on finding viable bounds than `RegionPlot`.  It certainly shows `RegionPlot` could be improved easily, I think.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. As I don't know beforehand what my regions will turn up to be, I calculate bounding rectangles on them and then pass appropriate values for region bounds in the final plot. It turns out `BoundingRegion` will happily return a rectangle even for an infinite line if it is passed through `DiscretizeRegion`.